# SPFx RelationshipDeleteBehavior not working during Web Part Provisioning

Tags: xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, provisioning, spfx

I am trying to provision two lists in a SP Modern WebPart for SP2019+. The second list has a lookup column referencing the first, but when I try to set the "RelationshipDeleteBehavior" on the second list I get an error when loading the WebPart App to a site.

Without including "RelationshipDeleteBehavior" the entire package deploys correctly, and the lookup column works as intended. The below is from my "elements.xml" file.

```
<Field
    ID="{UNIQUE GUID}"
    DisplayName="LookupColumn"
    Name="LookupColumn"
    StaticName="LookupColumn"
    Group="SPFx Test1"
    Type="Lookup"
    List="Lists/list1name"
    Indexed="TRUE"
    Mult="FALSE"
    Required="FALSE"
    EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
    ShowField="ID"
    UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE"
    RelationshipDeleteBehavior="Cascade"
/>
```

How do I provision the list with the cascade delete option set? In the "Site Columns" definition for the provisioned lookup field, it does not include the delete relationship field you normally get when editing the column settings from the list library directly. I also tried moving my field from the elements file to schema file to create it directly within the list vs provisioning a site column, but that too failed.

Provisioning Setup:

1. "elements.xml" file defines "List 1" fields, content type, and list instance.
2. List instance parameters references "schema1.xml" to create "List 1".
3. "elements.xml" file defines "List 2" fields, content type, and list instance.
4. List instance parameters reference "schema2.xml" to create "List 2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I added be below to the schema2.xml file instead of the elements.xml file in my "assets" folder:

```
<Fields>
    <Field
        ID="{UNIQUE GUID}"
        DisplayName="LookupColumn"
        Name="LookupColumn"
        StaticName="LookupColumn"
        Type="Lookup"
        List="Lists/list1name"
        Indexed="TRUE"
        Mult="FALSE"
        Required="FALSE"
        EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
        ShowField="ID"
        UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE"
        RelationshipDeleteBehavior="Cascade" 
        ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"
        ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
        ShowInNewForm="TRUE"
    />
</Fields>
```

Per the [SDK Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/aa979575(v=office.14)) for "RelationshipDeleteBehavior", a site column value must not be Cascade or Restrict. This restriction required placing the field in the list schema file in order to enable "Cascade" or "Restrict" behaviors. Additionally, since it is loaded to the specific list and not the provisioned content type, I had to add "ShowIn[Form Type]Form" to have the column display in the list forms.